# Jquery Ajax autocomplete: action of a controller not available

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, jquery, grails

I was trying to create an autocomplete field using jquery and ajax. I tried the code below but it gives me an error that the action of the controller is not available. Here is the code in my exeternal .js file:

```
$(function () {
  $("#inputfield").autocomplete({
    source: '<g:createLink controller="fruit" action="findFruit">'
  });
});
```

And this is the code from my Fruit controller:

```
def findFruit = {
  def fruitsearch= Fruit.withCriteria {
    ilike 'fruit', params.term + '%'
  }

  render (fruitsearch?.'fruit' as JSON)
}
```

I used firebug to see whats going on, and when I tried an input on the texfield, it says that the action findFruit is not available.

Am I missing something? Or is their something wrong on the code? Thanks

Comment: you're defining a method `findFruit=` but calling a method `findFruit`

Comment: Okay, So what would be their instead?

Comment: Which version of grails are you using, try defining actions as methods instead of closures [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9205209/why-should-grails-actions-be-declared-as-methods-instead-of-closures-and-what-di).

Comment: I am using grails version 2.0.1.

Comment: Okay, I tried changing it to action as a method ie def findFruit(){}, but still it has the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `js` code is evaluated from an external `js` file you should try using pure `js` code instead of grails tags (coz they won't work)

Try using relative path like:

```
$( "#inputfield" ).autocomplete({
    source: '/app-name/controller/action'
});
```

see if this works.