# Grails Method Signatures

Tags: grails, methods

What is the difference between these method signatures?

```
def myMethod = { //some code }
```

and

```
def myMethod () { //some code}
```

When would we want to use one over the other?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15602501/differences-between-action-and-methods-in-grails-controllers

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9205209/why-should-grails-actions-be-declared-as-methods-instead-of-closures-and-what-di?lq=1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Groovy : Closures or Methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825424/groovy-closures-or-methods)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1st one is a `Closure` while the 2nd one is a plain method.

Usually you stick with methods, as they have smaller meta-overhead. 
A Closure costs a bit more (0.5%) in terms of performance, but it gives you more groovy power. You can use it as a variable in all collection methods for example, or chain the closures together. The later is used in GORM to build-up the criteria queries