# what is the standard way for writing the groovy actions

Tags: grails, groovy

I am new to dynamic languages and now learning groovy & grails. I am little bit confused on how to write controller actions. In examples, i see two ways of writing actions:

```
1.
def action(args) {
    // do some action and render the result
}

2.
def action = { 
   // do some action
}
```

Can anyone explain what is the difference between these two syntax's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is a method, the second is a closure.

Since grails 2, you want to be doing methods in controllers

[Why should grails actions be declared as methods instead of closures and what difference does it make?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9205209/why-should-grails-actions-be-declared-as-methods-instead-of-closures-and-what-di)