# def function/method in Grails

Tags: grails, groovy, controller

A kind question, can anyone explain the difference between

```
def login() { 

     //some codes here 

}
```

to

```
def login = {

    //some codes here

}
```

in Grails. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I'm just kind a new in groovy and grails programming.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9205209/why-should-grails-actions-be-declared-as-methods-instead-of-closures-and-what-di

Comment: You would most likely want to stick with methods instead of closures unless you have some very specific usecase, grails no longer recommends closure actions and may be even removed in future versions.

Comment: Please, @Mystique, if Joshua Moore gave a satisfactory answer, be a Mensch and confirm.

Comment: sorry @loteq for not acknowledging Joshua Moore's answer right away. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is: `def login() { .. }` is a method while `def login = { ... }` is a closure. Older versions of Grails controllers used closures for their actions while later versions use methods (which is where you likely see this difference).

If you want to learn more, read up on Groovy closures.

Comment: And methods preferred as actions over closures.

Comment: It depends on what problem you are trying to solve. Closures are different than methods and thus can be used differently. Unless you have a reason to use a closure you should just use a method. That's my personal advice to you.

Comment: Yup, thats what i am saying, in most of situations methods are preffered over closures, and thts why grails team decided to go with methods

Comment: It's more than just preference as to /why/ controllers were moved to methods instead of closures, but that's not really relevant. Hope the answer addresses your question (if so, you might want to mark it as accepted).

Comment: Here's my answer which is copied from grails docs and this says it all why methods were preferred over closures http://stackoverflow.com/a/9205312/1001816

Comment: Thanks @Joshua Moore , it helps a lot.

Comment: @Mystique, no worries. You're welcome. Glad it helped.