# What is the difference between two types defining a functions grails

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-controller

**Method** 1:

```
def funtion1(){
//Code here
}
```

**Method** 2:

```
def function2={
//code here
}
```

actually what are the difference between defining these two type of method... And which one is good ..

Comment: Hey, could you please accept my answer, if it's correct?

Answer (score 2):

Controller Actions as Methods
It is now possible to define controller actions as methods instead of using closures as in previous versions of Grails.

**[In fact this is now the preferred way of expressing an action](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/introduction.html#webFeatures)**.

So, if you use grails > 2.*, define actions as **methods** instead of as clothures.

Similar questions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/1827035/1815058
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/9205312/1815058

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first one if a function and the second is a closure.

**A Groovy Closure is like a "code block" or a method pointer. It is a piece of code that is defined and then executed at a later point. It has some special properties like implicit variables, support for currying and support for free variables**.

I think that traditional methods is what you need. You probably should use closures in some special cases, but it's really big topic for thought.

So you better read about closures [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Closures) and may be [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-pg06239/index.html).