# Groovy - closures vs methods - the difference

Tags: groovy, closures, anonymous-inner-class

[image]

If you look very carefully at the picture included, you will notice that you can refactor Groovy code using the Eclipse IDE and convert a method to a closure and vice versa. So, what exactly is a closure again and how is it different than a method? Can someone give a good example of using a closure as well as why it's a useful feature? Anonymous inner classes weren't good enough?

Comment: I've removed the `java` tag, as the question is purely about the Groovy language, not the JVM it runs on or the Java language.

Comment: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Closures

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Closure is a **Closure class instance**, that implements Call logic. 
It may be passed as argument or assigned to a variable. It also has some logic concerned with scope variable accessing and delegating calls.

Methods are normal Java methods. Nothing special.

And yes, anonymous inner classes have a lot of boilerplate code to perform simple actions.

Compare:

```
button.addActionListener(
  new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
          frame.dispose();
     }
  }
);
```

vs

```
button.addActionListener { frame.dispose() }
```

There is a related question on SO [Groovy : Closures or Methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825424/groovy-closures-or-methods)
and the following link(s) to the user guide containing a lot of useful information.

1. http://groovy-lang.org/closures.html

> A closure in Groovy is an open, anonymous, block of code that can take
>   arguments, return a value and be assigned to a variable. A closure may
>   reference variables declared in its surrounding scope. In opposition
>   to the formal definition of a closure, Closure in the Groovy language
>   can also contain free variables which are defined outside of its
>   surrounding scope. While breaking the formal concept of a closure, it
>   offers a variety of advantages which are described in this chapter.

Comment: See [some reasons why](http://www.javanicus.com/blog2/items/191-index.html) your example isn't a true lexical closure, and even Groovy's creator called it "fundamentally broken".

Comment: @VorgvanGeir Many thanks for interesting link but I'm not sure that it is correlated to OP's question.

Comment: @Seagull The codehaus links you have posted, are no longer available. Can you please update them with this: http://groovy-lang.org/closures.html . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Also, as Closures are first class objects, they can be passed around, returned and manipulated.  Consider:

```
def add = { n, m -> n + m }
def add2 = add.curry( 2 )

assert add2( 4 ) == 6

def makeAdder = { n ->
    // return a Closure
    { m -> n + m }
}
def anotherAdd2 = makeAdder( 2 )

assert anotherAdd2( 4 ) == 6
```

Answer (score 0):

A closure in Groovy is an open, anonymous, block of code that can take arguments, return a value and be assigned to a variable. 
The following link containing a lot of useful information.
http://www.groovy-lang.org/closures.html

Answer (score 0):

I think Closure is closely relating to functional interface in Java that implements `Call` method. It's anonymous, can has as many as input needed, can return a data type.

Maybe it's useful in defining event handlers or listeners.