# How does 'f(x) { return x }' differ from 'f = { x -> x }'?

Tags: function, groovy

Given this Groovy program:

```
def f(x) { return x }

g = f

println g(42)
```

When feeding the program to the Groovy (version 2.4.12) interpreter, an error message is printed:

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: f for class: x
>       at x.run(x.groovy:3)

However, changing the program to

```
def f = { x -> x }

g = f

println g(42)
```

Makes the interpreter print '42', as expected.

Why are these two definitions of `f` treated differently? Is there a way to adjust the definition of `g` such that the former version runs (maybe using the `&.` operator)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With:

```
def f(x) { return x }
```

you define a method which is not an object whereas with:

```
def f = { x -> x }
```

you define a closure which is an object in terms of groovy.

These are not equivalent beings. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21905550/groovy-closures-vs-methods-the-difference).

You can indeed use `&` operator (in *turns* a method into closure):

```
def f(x) { return x }

def g = this.&f

println g(42)
```

Comment: Ah, I see - I didn't realise that methods are not objects in the Groovy sense! Thanks, that explains it. And indeed, using `this.&f` works.